# How to use a method with a pipe operator

Tags: powershell

This command returns the expected result

```
'd   d' -replace '\s+', ' ' | echo
```

> 'd d'

Now I want ot use this method replace on the content of a file.

```
new-Item a.txt
echo 'd   d' >a.txt

cat a.txt| -replace '\s+', ' ' | echo
```

> -replace : The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

[code](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py@1XNezJDVXIVGvpKKEKzU5I19BPUVBQSFFXcEOIpacWAKV5YLJ6BalFuQkJqcqqMcUa6vrKKgDYY0CSDNCdQ0eVf//AwA)

Comment: `-replace` is an operator - you can't pipe to an operator.  Try something like this: `(cat a.txt) -replace '\s+', ' ' | echo`

Answer (score 1):

As boxdog proposed, this works for my case:

```
(cat a.txt) -replace '\s+', ' ' | echo
```

[code](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py@1XNezJDVXIVGvpKKEKzU5I19BPUVBQSFFXcEOIpacWAKV5YLJ6BalFuQkJqcqqMcUa6vrKKgDYY0CSDOXBly5Jh5l//8DAA)